# После записи в базу MySQL возвращается неполное значение

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Всем привет! Делаю PHP движок – регистрацию. Все работает норм, кроме того, что в базу имя пользователя записывается неполное. Вот примеры:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Должно было быть `Oughson` а пришло `O`. Тип строки: `VARCHAR(36)`

Еще скажу что записывается в базу все очень примитивным запросом:

```css
mysqli_query($dataBase, 'INSERT INTO `Users` VALUES ("","'.$_SESSION['user']['email'].'", "'.$_SESSION['user']['name']['email'].'", "'.$_SESSION['user']['password'].'", "'.$_SESSION['user']['gender'].'")');
```

Еще если поможет, то я записываю данные в базу из сессии с совсем другого файла.

Comment: Несоответствие кавычек, как я вижу... Используйте подстановку `"{$_SESSION['user']['email']}"` - меньше мороки с кавычками

Comment: @DNS Так не очень. Имя элемента массива без кавычек приходиться писать.

Comment: var_dump($_SESSION) гляньте что там, может там уже урезанные данные.

Comment: @Jean-Claude В сессии все нормально выводит.

Comment: @Jean-Claude Я реально не знаю почему так вышло, но все оказалось проще.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почему-то была какая-то проблема с кавычками в запросе (как и говорил DNS)

> Несоответствие кавычек, как я вижу... Используйте подстановку "{$_SESSION['user']['email']}" - меньше мороки с кавычками – DNS

Но только я сделал так и оно заработало:

```
<?php mysqli_query($dataBase, "INSERT INTO `Users` VALUES ('','".$_SESSION['user']['email']."', '".$_SESSION['user']['name']."', '".$_SESSION['user']['password']."', '".$_SESSION['user']['gemder']."')");?>
```